# Cursor adapter on layout issue

Tags: java, android

Hoping this is a simple one!

Can anyone tell me why my layout is being shown in my list view rather than my actual returned data?

For example, if I have 2 names in my database called 'John' I send the name 'John' from my 'EditText' to query the database, the correct number of listview cells is made, but it displays the layout again twice rather than the returned details!

output issue with the duplicate edit text and button in the listview:

I have one person called 'Dave' in my database, so it is showing the correct result number in the list view, i.e '1', but the issue is it should show their name, contact no, email and a comment, NOT the layout again!

[image: i]

search XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inputSearchName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type Name To Search:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearchName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Search code:

```
    search.open();
Cursor cursor = search.searchOnName(searchedName);

startManagingCursor(cursor);

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
String [] from = new String [] {DBsearchRef.KEY_NAME, DBsearchRef.KEY_TEL, DBsearchRef.KEY_EMAIL, DBsearchRef.KEY_COMMENTS};
int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtNameList, R.id.txtTelList, R.id.txtEmailList, R.id.txtCommentsList};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.search, cursor, from, to);
searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

The issue is my 'search' class layout is being shown in the listview....but as the listview is part of this class, i thought this would be the correct reference?

Comment: I don't understand: "but it displays the layout again twice rather than the returned details!" Could you post `search.xml` and possibly a screenshot of what is happening? Do you see any errors?

Comment: when the name changes, you need to reload this cursor and swap the old for the new. have you done this?

Comment: Mango, could you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: Sam, No, there are no errors. I will added them now.

Comment: I only found your response by luck... Use `@Sam` to reply to a particular user. (This will send a notification to that user. You receive notifications by default because we are commenting on your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why my layout is being shown in my list view rather than my actual returned data?

The XML layout you pass to the Adapter, here:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.search, cursor, from, to);
```

Is the layout that will be used in each row. Clearly you do not want to use `search.xml`, simply change `R.layout.search` to the layout that you want to use.

---

**Addition**
Try this code, it might help you understand the difference:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        cursor, 
        new String[] {DBsearchRef.KEY_NAME}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Comment: This is where i become a little confused sam as 'search' contains the listview, so I thought this would be the layout i need to use? Or do I simply create a new XML layout with a listview?

Comment: I was confused on that when I first started too. The _Activity_ should contain the layout with the ListView, typically passed with `setContentView()`. But the ListView _rows_ are defined in the Adapter. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes and no (sorry for my noobness here), My activity is set out with a edit text, a button then a listview. Do i need to set a new layout with a listview that will use a listview on its own? I just tried that and it goes blank. Do i need to delete the original listview from my activity i.e the one in 'search'?

Comment: I posted slightly different code, give it a try then look at the layout in [`simple_list_item_1.xml`](https://bitbucket.org/tanepiper/learning-android-examples/src/b979b18a5a0e/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) Notice that the row layout is only a TextView.

Comment: Sam thanks for the code, I have had a go at adapting it but cant seem to get eclipse to recognise the new XML layout.

Comment: sorry to ask yet another question, but is the XML layout you have provided within a linear layout? Or a pure TextView XML layout?

Comment: It is a single TextView (no LinearLayout), but you can use any valid layout. Are you trying to build a custom layout? If so post what you have so far in your question.

Comment: many thanks. I was in the right area about 3 hours ago when pulling my hair out! But its sorted now, again, thank you.